# Columns taking the size of the smallest device in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Instead of taking the size of the appropriate device width, the columns in bootstrap always takes the smallest set size. This causes all my input to be full sized in navigator instead of being respectively 3/4th - 1/4th, like my code should do. Every other style elements works just fine.

Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <?php include("head.php");?>

    <body>
        <?php include("nav.php");?>

        <form method='post'>
            <h2 class='sr-only'>Informations d'entreprise</h2>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input class='form-control' name='entreprise' type='text' placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-12'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <input class='form-control' name='telephone' type='tel' placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </form>

        <?php include("footer.php");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/6apc4h7s/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method='post'>
    <h2 class='sr-only'>Informations d'entreprise</h2>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-9'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input class='form-control' name='entreprise' type='text' placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input class='form-control' name='telephone' type='tel' placeholder="Numéro de téléphone" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Always you should specify the class in the order of small to large device.

Like the below code:

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3'>
```

Comment: Welcome @Firelumet :)